# How to handle HTTP services after Jan 2017 in IOS Apps?

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store, ios9, ios10

Recently I got to know that Apple is no more going to support HTTP services and they are making HTTPS as mandatory. Here is the link they specified clearly.https://techcrunch.com/2016/06/14/apple-will-require-https-connections-for-ios-apps-by-the-end-of-2016/

Now my problem is we are using many APIs which are not HTTPS they are just HTTP. And our app is in app store. We can't make those services into HTTPS now itself. So as told in the link those APIs are not gonna work. Please give me some solution so that I can overcome this problem. I want all my APIs to work after Jan 2017.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is no solution of this except-

You will need to make all your APIs HTTPS support.
And you will need to update your App to call HTTPS services and submit again.

Answer (score 0):

If it's a problem of pricing you could secure your APIs with self signed certificates and import them into the app. Also it would be possible to be your own CA. So you can create a lot of certificates without importing them all into the devices, which are using your app.
You have just to import the root CA certificate. You could do that with an option in your app.
Otherwise I think there is no solution. I'm not sure how apple handles already existing apps in the app store. Maybe they will work a little bit longer.

When I remember correctly apple said that developers could ask for exemptions. (Was mentioned in the last WWDC)

Comment: How can I do this self-signed

Comment: How to create self signed certificate: http://www.akadia.com/services/ssh_test_certificate.html
I would suggest to create your own CA and create some certificates with that CA. Then import your root CA cert into the devices which are using your app. (You could add an option to download and import it via your app).
How to be your own CA: https://jamielinux.com/docs/openssl-certificate-authority/